# Why is this person still alive in the ending?

Tags: psycho-pass

I just finished watching Psycho Pass 2, an was wondering why Kamui Kirito is shown in the ending, sitting inside an isolation chamber?

It's clearly shown how Sakuya Togane and Kamui shoot each other: Kamui is getting a direct hit, and Togane loses his arm resulting in his death a few minutes later. I don't get how Kamui should have survived this...

[image: Ending Scene]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kamui Kirito is dead.

The image you posted from the ED of episode 11 is of [Mizue Shisui](http://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Mizue_Shisui), the inspector that Kamui kidnaps.

[image]

She is usually seen with an eyepatch over here left eye. The eye that she's covering is the eye that Kamui used to wield the dominators.

Comment: oh lol, you are right :D

Comment: i failed hard... damn it